# Where to store site specific information like site name, admin email, etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When creating say a cms application where website specific details will vary depending on the website, where should I be storing this information?

Things like:  site name, support email, smtp settings, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean configuration data for the application, here's what I do:

I create a `config/app_config.yml` file with my config information, like this:

```
site_name: This awesome site
support_email: me@mysite.com
```

Then, at the top of `config/application.rb` (right below the first 'require' statement), I add this:

```
# Load application-specific configuration from app_config.yml
require 'yaml'
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../app_config.yml', __FILE__)))
```

Now, any time I need to access the configuration data, I can get to it via the APP_CONFIG hash, like so:

```
html = "For support, please e-mail #{APP_CONFIG['support_email']}"
```

Note, the above is for Rails 3.  For rails 2, instead of loading the config in application.rb, you would put the statements into config/preinitializer.rb.

See http://asciicasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2 for more details.

Comment: perfect that is just what I am after.

Comment: since app_config.yml is in the same folder as application.rb, why do you have ../app_config.yml and not just app_config.yml?

Comment: The \_\_FILE\_\_ argument that we're using as a base is the file currently being executed... so it resolves to `myapp/config/application.rb`. If you don't add the "..", then it tries to load `myapp/config/application.rb/app_config.yml`.

Comment: I see, I would have thought ../ would go to myapp/app_config.yml

Answer (score 1):

Setting like this.

```
$ vi config/environments/development.rb
config.site_name = "Your Site Name"
config.site_url = "localhost:3000"
```

Also you can use 'application.rb' environments.

```
$ vi config/application.rb
module YourAppName
 class Application < Rails::Application
   config.site_name = "Your Site Name"
```

How to use it.

```
<%= YourAppName::Application.config.site_name %>
@url = YourAppName::Application.config.site_url
```

You can check your AppName from here

```
$ vi config/application.rb
module YourAppName
 class Application < Rails::Application
```